# Return a result bigger than 1MiB in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way to return a value from an `Activity` that is larger than 1 MiB? I have a byte array that is 2 MiB big and if I try and return it in the usual way from an activity (startActivityForResult, setResult, finish) I get a

```
"JavaBinder FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" error.
```

I understand there is a 1MiB limit of data passed through intents. So how can I return a value bigger than 1 MiB?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I like this answer but you could assign the data to a field in an application class and then read it from the activity you return to.  Hacky, but it should work.  Then return a boolean to let the calling activity know whether or not you successfully set the data.

Comment: Yeah, I've also got my own hack for it, but I was hoping the android designers had thought of this possibility.